# how to pass the button id from one page to another page in php

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

I have created dynamic buttons in my php code ,i need to get that created dynamic button id to another page in php for getting the value from database.

I need to pass that button click id to the sql QUERY.
How can i pass value following is code here created dynamic button code?

```php
<?php
function dash()
{
  include 'config.php';
  $sql = "SELECT  RoomNumber  FROM roommaster ";
  if ($result = mysqli_query($db, $sql)) {
    $str = '';
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
      // generate array from comma delimited list
      $rooms = explode(',', $row['RoomNumber']);
      //create the dynamic button and set the value
      foreach ($rooms as $v) {
        $str .= "<input type='button'  name='b1' id='btn' value='" . $v . "' />";
      }
    }
    return $str;
  } else {
    echo "ERROR: Could not able to execute $sql. " . mysqli_error($db);
  }
  mysqli_close($db);
}
?>

<!Doctype html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>room boking</title>

  <link href="css/bootstrap1.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/front.css">
  <script src='http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js'></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

</head>

<body>
  <form mathod="post" action="booking.php">
    <div class="  row box col-md-4">
      <div style="color:black">
        <?php echo dash();?>
      </div>
    </div>


  </form>


</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Phew, thats a really big example. Please check this: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: See i have edit. tell me how to pass that id to another page

Comment: You can use [`input[type="hidden"]`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/hidden) for this.

Comment: could you please explain me in detail

Comment: You already have everything. Just pick up the value of b1 in the next page, just like all other form values.

Comment: @Yogesh that why I linked it. Please read the article and if you don't understand, let me know..

Answer (score 0):

You can send the id value inside a input type hidden, like next:

```
<input type="hidden" value="btn" name="buttonID">
```

Answer (score 0):

In booking.php use `$_POST['b1']`, where `b1` is the name of the input, to get the value the same as any other form input.

Comment: i have tried but it gives error undefined variable b1